# Logging into iCloud on the simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, icloud

The iOS Simulator is rejecting my logins with test accounts as invalid username/password, even after Simulator > Reset Content and Settings.

When I try to create a real account, I get prompted when logging into icloud.com that I need to log in on a real device to use icloud.

Is there a way to log in as a test account and use iCloud in 8.2?

Answer (score 1):

You likely have 2-factor authentication enabled for your account.  This is not supported in the iOS Simulator.  You should create a separate account for development without 2-factor auth.

Comment: I do not have 2 factor.

Comment: Then this is unexpected.  I'm able to login with my account just fine.  Please file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com and include a tarball of ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator and indicate the approximate time you tried to connect and the device UDID you were using (you can see that in 'xcrun simctl list'